# Prevent newline in iput box after return key pressed

Tags: html, form-submit

Am using the following function to submit a form in the html:

```
if(event.keyCode==13) {submitComment('.$id.');}
```

However in the second of so before the JS fires, a newline is created and looks silly.

how can i prevent a newline creation and just use return to submit the form?

Comment: Which event are you using? Use keyDown and preventDefault.

Comment: keyup, but can change doesnt matter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cancel action...

```
if(event.keyCode==13) {submitComment('.$id.'); return false;}
```

Or if you are using JQuery:

```
if(event.keyCode==13) {submitComment('.$id.');event.preventDefault();}
```